# Error in library(RWordPress) : there is no package called ‘RWordPress’

Tags: r, wordpress, blogs, install.packages

I am trying to upload my rmarkdown to wordpress using the RWordPress package. I am trying to use the method used [here](https://sites.tufts.edu/emotiononthebrain/2017/08/12/blog-posting-from-r-markdown-to-wordpress/) by Duncan Lang, but it keeps returning error messages.

Here is the exact code that I used (just copied from the website):

```
if (!require('RWordPress')) {devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))}
```

And here are the output I get:

Loading required package: RWordPress
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Downloading GitHub repo duncantl/XMLRPC@HEAD
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Phillip's PC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeEZg02\remotes67a46471e82\duncantl-XMLRPC-add9496/DESCRIPTION' ...

- preparing 'XMLRPC':
  √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
- checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
- checking for empty or unneeded directories
- building 'XMLRPC_0.3-1.tar.gz'
  Warning: file 'XMLRPC/Web/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'XMLRPC' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::makeLazyLoading("XMLRPC", "C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-XMLRPC/00new", keep.source = FALSE, keep.parse.data = FALSE, set.install.dir = 'C:/Users/Phillip's"
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'XMLRPC'
- removing 'C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/XMLRPC'
  Error: Failed to install 'XMLRPC' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/PHILLI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeEZg02/file67a45b592144/XMLRPC_0.3-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
  In addition: Warning message:
  In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :

Error: Failed to install 'XMLRPC' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/PHILLI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeEZg02/file67a45b592144/XMLRPC_0.3-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

UPDATE
I updated to latest version of R and Rstudio
Installed the latest version of Rtools

When I run this code:

```
install.packages("Rtools")
```

I get this message:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/Radmin.html#Installing-packages

I followed the steps according to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ with no issues.

I can't seem to successfully install Rtools. I have tried redownloading it and restarting R. No luck.

****UPDATE

I tried:

```
devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))
```

and got:

Downloading GitHub repo duncantl/XMLRPC@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Phillip's PC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMPnz2M\remotes46a06ff1790e\duncantl-XMLRPC-add9496/DESCRIPTION' ...

- preparing 'XMLRPC':
  √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
- checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
- checking for empty or unneeded directories
- building 'XMLRPC_0.3-1.tar.gz'
  Warning: file 'XMLRPC/Web/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'XMLRPC' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::makeLazyLoading("XMLRPC", 'C:/Users/Phillip's"
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'XMLRPC'
- removing 'C:/Users/Phillip's PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/XMLRPC'
  Error: Failed to install 'XMLRPC' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/PHILLI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMPnz2M/file46a05e4b6976/XMLRPC_0.3-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: updated my post with the full output

Comment: Well, from the output we see that "Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed." You can download Rtools from: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html. It also appears that you are running an older version of R. You might want to update to R4.0 while you are at it, or download the older version of RTools for R3.6

Comment: I see it now, thanks. I'll try this solution and report back later. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my post. I updated R, Rstudio, and downloaded Rtools. I followed the steps according to cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html. I am having a problem at the Rtools steps. I'm not sure if I downloaded it wrong or what I am doing.

Comment: Rtools is not an R package that you can install. You never need to run `install.packages("Rtools")`. Just try to run the `devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))` code now. If Rtools was successfully installed, at the very least you should get a different error message.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and still not working. Output has been updated in the original posting @MrFlick

Comment: It looks like you have spaces in your file path where you are trying to install the package. So it's either the quote or the apostrophe in "Philip's PC" that's causing the commands to build the package to fail. Check out more about that here: https://lcolladotor.github.io/2019/09/18/windows-user-space-issues-with-installing-r-packages/#.X41MltBKhaQ